# How to set variables during a project build in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I have some Python project, like a library.
I have also two Azure DevOps environment feeds, NPRD and PROD for example. There are two different pipelines for build and post artifacts.

Now I need to define some different constants in my code for these envs, like URLS, end-points, etc. Maybe part of them I want to be secured. My built artifact (whl actually) will work on some user machine which I don't have access to and I can't define environment variables for my properties.

So how can I inject these values to the project during pipeline build? Is it possible?

Comment: What you need are *environment variables*. You declare them in both environment feeds, and access them from Python code with `os.environ['ENV_VAR_NAME']`.

Comment: I don't exactly know about Azure, but what you should do (AFAIU your problem) is to provide those resources remotely, either through some (minimal) GET interface, for example. Put that on your Python project, in the initialization of the pipeline. In the simplest case, on your server side, you can just make a file-server with some `.ini`/`.json` files and get them with Python' urllib (from the client). That's a five minutes solution.

Comment: it's not a problem to define environment variable of a pipeline container, but how to inject them inside the code or properties file of the artifact?